# Send int value to PC from Android

Tags: android, sockets, client

I managed to set up a server(on PC) and a Client (on device)  thru the IP address .Now I want to send a meesage to the PC to move left or right depending if I hit the volume up or down...

Client:

```
   @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) 
    {
        mtcpclient.write(1); //I need to implement write function..
        return true;
    }
    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){
        mtcpclient.write(2);//I need to implement write function..
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Server:

```
private void processCommand(int command) {//Recieve int and decide to go right or left
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        switch (command) {
        case 1:
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
            System.out.println("Right");
            break;
        case 2:
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
            System.out.println("Left");
            break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: good luck. What is your problem?

Comment: need to implement the write function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is how to send data...here is a simple example on how to send data via TCP.

```
String message = "Message to server";
String ipAdd = "127.0.0.1";
int port = 6789;
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName(ipAdd);
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
outToServer.writeBytes(message);
outToServer.flush();
clientSocket.close();
```

Then you just need to write a similar listener on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the response of Kevin , but The emulator is considered like an other machine, so you must change the ipAdd by the Adress of your PC, and normally that should work .

Good luck ;)

Comment: I simply used localhost as an example IP.  I didn't mean to imply it was the address to be used.